# Item sheet using Point

Tags: c#, xna

I'm creating an RPG-esque game in C# with XNA and I want to implement items (as all RPGs do). I understand the easy approach would be have each item assigned their own .png but to cut down on space I want to use a sprite sheet. Is there a way of doing this using Point and Rectangle? I've tried many different things but I'm not entirely sure how I should go about doing this.

Comment: If all your textures have the same width/height a way to do it would be storing in your items their X and Y position on the sprite sheet. With sb.Draw, you can use that X and Y to create the "source rectangle" to draw only the correct portion of the spritesheet. However, that would mean storing somewhere all your indexes (by that I mean either a huge switch case in a factory, or one class per item), which is not really great. Honestly, unless you're doing a huge high-end game you won't see a performance hit at all by using multiple pngs, I'd stick to that.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll give up on that. :P Thanks for the info!

Comment: Honestly what Pierre suggested is definitely the best solution, even if you don't plan on making a big game. You may not see a bit performance hit, but managing files will be so much easier if you use a spritesheet. I have done this very thing myself, and trust me, if you implement it right, you'll barely notice it's there when you use it in code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple XNA tutorial for XNA tile based games here [http://www.xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=Tutorial:TileEngineSeries:1](http://www.xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=Tutorial%3aTileEngineSeries:1)